# How to make function run even if getUsername() is null

Tags: magento2, php, php-7.3

How can I make this function run - also when getUsername() is null

```
$authSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
$UUsername = $authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
$glsDirName = $this->directoryList->getPath('var') . '/GLS/' . $UUsername;
```

> [2021-01-16 06:25:09] main.ERROR: Cron Job gls_import_tracking has an
> error: Call to a member function getUsername() on null. Statistics:
> {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":223346688,"emalloc_start":220510920}
> [] [] [2021-01-16 06:25:09] main.CRITICAL: Error when running a cron
> job {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Error when
> running a cron job at
> /bbb/bbb/www/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php:362,
> Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getUsername() on null at
> /bbb/bbb/www/vendor/tric/module-gls/Helper/Data.php:453)"} []

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted, if it helped you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you're getting user from AuthSession Model first, you can accomplish this by using following code;

```
$authSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
$user =  $authSession->getUser();
if($user) {
   // does not run if there are no available user in auth session
   $UUsername = $user->getUsername();
   $glsDirName = $this->directoryList->getPath('var') . '/GLS/' . $UUsername;
}
```